# Combine nested list into unique combinations of sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, combinations

I have a nested list of the form:

```
[[[a, [a1, a2, a3]],[b, [b1, b2, b3]], [c, [c1, c2, c3]]]
```

How can I get this into unique combinations of the initial elements, of the form:

```
[[[a, b],[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3]],[[a,c],[a1, a2, a3, c1, c2, c3]], [[b,c],[b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]]]
```

I know that's a lot of lists, but I need it in that form. I don't have an idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [['a', ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']],['b', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']], ['c', ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]]
print([[[i for i, _ in c], [i for _, l in c for i in l]] for c in combinations(l, 2)])
```

This outputs:

`[[['a', 'b'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']], [['a', 'c'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']], [['b', 'c'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']]]`

Comment: I beat you to it. See the other answer :)

Comment: Good job, though keep in mind that iterating through indices isn't the Pythonic way.

Comment: You are right, your answer is more elegant than mine, so I will choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it. Here is a working example.

```
test = [['a', ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']],['b', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']], ['c', ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]]

nested_list = []
for (idx1, idx2) in itertools.combinations(range(len(test)), r=2):
    (elem1, elem2), (elem3, elem4) = test[idx1], test[idx2]
    nested_list += [[elem1, elem3], elem2+elem4]

nested_list

[['a', 'b'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
 ['a', 'c'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

L = [['a', ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']], ['b', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']], ['c', ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]]

d = dict(L)

res = {comb: list(chain.from_iterable(map(d.__getitem__, comb))) \
       for comb in combinations(d, 2)}
```

Result:

```
{('a', 'b'): ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
 ('a', 'c'): ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
 ('b', 'c'): ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']}
```

Or, if you prefer nested lists:

```
res_lst = [[list(comb), list(chain.from_iterable(map(d.__getitem__, comb)))] \
           for comb in combinations(d, 2)]

# [[['a', 'b'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']],
#  [['a', 'c'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']],
#  [['b', 'c'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']]]
```

The idea, in both cases, is to reduce the number of Python-level `for` loops.